# Is repirator easier to breathe through than conventional medical mask?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, face-mask-respirator, protection

Currently I'm using [conventional blue mask](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=mask&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fae01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FHTB1HjSbMXXXXXbKXFXXq6xXFXXXS%2F10pcs-Medical-masks-Non-woven-disposable-anti-dust-mouth-mask-Anti-virus-mask-Mouth-muffle-Flu.jpg).
But there are masks with exhale valve (there are mostly FFP2 ones and they're cheaper, I'm considering [to buy one](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=respirator%20exhaust%20valve&t=canonical&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sierra12.com%2Fuploads%2F2%2F9%2F5%2F2%2F29525509%2F1002798_orig.jpg), for COVID protection). I didn't try such and it's hard to find information about this aspect on the Internet.

Comment: I have several real N95 masks, because I didn't throw them away after doing grinding and sanding for paint prep. Doctors don't want em when they're covered in lead paint dust :) **This is an active physical activity** and much of the work was on ladders or otherwise in stress positions. Real N95s seal well and are harder to breathe through.   As such, **the "hard to breathe" argument is not believable to me**. You may "feel" unaccustomed to breathing through them, but rest assured, you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Masks with exhalation valves are meant to be used to protect against particulates like sawdust or smoke. [They must not be used in a pandemic because a large part of the usefulness of masks is **preventing people who are infected and don't know it from spreading the virus**. If you have an exhalation valve on your mask you're exposing everyone around you.](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/hcp/respirator-use-faq.html)

Public health guidelines would suggest you continue to use a surgical mask and do not advise using masks with exhalation valves.

Comment: It is permissible to use a mask with an exhale valve **if you also put a surgical mask on top of it**. However double-masking would presumably defeat OP's purpose.